# MQ Thread hangs

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

I have a setup with a MQ Queue and a Liberty application taking messages from MQ an puts them into a database.

After random number of messages going nice and clean through I get a timeout exception (see below) When this happens it seems like the thread hangs utilizing 100% CPU, the more this happens the higher load on the server. Any suggestions?

com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTimeoutManager I WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[Default Executor-thread-37,5,Default Executor Thread Group]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.receiveOneTSH(RemoteSession.java:884) com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.receive1stGetReplyTSH(RemoteSession.java:1509) com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetMessageWithProps(RemoteFAP.java:9820) com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.MQGET(RemoteFAP.java:9511) com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.MQGET(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:1213) com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.MQGET(ESEJMQI.java:430) com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.compat.base.internal.MQSESSION.MQGET(MQSESSION.java:975) com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.compat.base.internal.MQQueue.getMsg2Int(MQQueue.java:1355) com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.compat.base.internal.MQQueue.getMsg2NoExc(MQQueue.java:1445) com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQSession.consume(MQSession.java:1865) com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQSession.loadMessageReference(MQSession.java:4224) com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.consume(JmsSessionImpl.java:3639) com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:3227) com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:937) com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ASFWorkImpl.doDelivery(ASFWorkImpl.java:110) com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.AbstractWorkImpl.run(AbstractWorkImpl.java:229) com.ibm.ws.jca.inbound.security.JCASecurityContextService.runInInboundSecurityContext(JCASecurityContextService.java:49) com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:354) com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualRunnable.run(ContextualRunnable.java:79) com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:285) com.ibm.ws.jca.internal.WorkProxy.call(WorkProxy.java:58) java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)

Comment: What version of IBM MQ resource adapter are you using?

Comment: We're using 9.1.0.0 but running against an old MQ server v6.0.1.0. Not sure if that is the issue

Comment: MQ9.1 requires java 7 or later.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. the MQ resource adapter runs on the Liberty, which runs java 7